# Wrong positioning and scaling of SVG-image on PdfCanvas

Tags: c#, itext7

I recently had to move from iTextSharp to iText 7 because of SVG support.
What I found is, that scaling and positioning a vector image on top of a PdfCanvas seem very off to me compared to the definition inside the vector image.

This is my function which adds the vector image to the canvas:

```cs
private static void AddImageToCanvas(Document document, DocumentFileModel documentfile, ImageData image, string stampdata)
{
    var pageSize = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4.GetWidth(), PageSize.A4.GetHeight());
    var docpage = document.GetPdfDocument().AddNewPage(new PageSize(pageSize));
    var canvas = new PdfCanvas(docpage);
    canvas.AddImage(image, pageSize, false);
    SvgConverter.DrawOnCanvas(stampdata, canvas);
    if (image.GetWidth() > image.GetHeight())
        docpage.SetRotation(90);
}
```

**stampdata** contains the vector image data as string:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="ansvgroot" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ansvg="http://dev.elform.net/public/ansvg" viewBox="0 0 1015 276" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      text {
        text-antialiasing: true;
        text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
      }
      image {
        image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g transform="scale(0.05)">
    <g ansvg:layer="0" ansvg:type="TextStamp" ansvg:id="e7c69dd4-aecc-4220-9dae-d84f6b076f51">
      <text x="1423" y="924" style="font-family:'Microsoft Sans Serif',Geneva,sans-serif; font-size:220px; fill:#0000ff; white-space: nowrap" xml:space="preserve">Info: JPG</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Since this image will be auto generated, I have no control over its structure or content.

Adding the image to the canvas, it looks like this:

[this is wrong](http://gaebolg.com/pub/elform/download_KREDITOR_241_3876fd2e-c7e3-4aec-946f-d9e20674796f-2.png)

whereas it should look like this (this is from the web frontend, where the vector image is added as an overlay to a div, containing the background image)

[this is correct](http://gaebolg.com/pub/elform/download_KREDITOR_241_3876fd2e-c7e3-4aec-946f-d9e20674796f-1.png)

Am I missing something? Can anyone guide me, to get it looking like the second image, when creating a pdf and adding the vector image to the canvas?
Also, any idea why the color turned black all of a sudden?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I got some time to test if the latest iText 7 (7.1.9) version can handle the svg annotations that were added automatically.
Unfortunately positioning and size is still off compared to what it should look like.

First things first - this is the svg data container that is generated by the software:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="ansvgroot" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ansvg="http://dev.elform.net/public/ansvg" viewBox="0 0 595 842" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">text{text-antialiasing:true;text-rendering:geometricPrecision}
image{image-rendering:optimizeQuality}</style>
  </defs>
  <g transform="scale(0.05)">
    <g ansvg:layer="0" ansvg:type="BitmapStamp" ansvg:id="21ba6cd3-9126-4130-8c1e-41a54fa9de14">
      <rect x="73" y="7924" width="6855" height="7403" stroke="#FF0000" fill="none" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="20" />
      <text x="123" y="8194" style="font-family:'Arial',sans-serif; font-size:220px; fill:#FF0000; white-space: nowrap">
        <tspan x="123" dy="0" xml:space="preserve">tannert</tspan>
        <tspan x="123" dy="242" xml:space="preserve">31.12.2019, 22:38</tspan>
      </text>
      <image x="123" y="8507" width="6797" height="6812" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" />
    </g>
    <g ansvg:layer="0" ansvg:type="TextStamp" ansvg:id="af164cb3-2957-45b9-8a6b-7964d411dc10">
      <text x="7196" y="8189" style="font-family:'Microsoft Sans Serif',Geneva,sans-serif; font-size:160px; fill:#0000FF; white-space: nowrap" xml:space="preserve">Freitext</text>
    </g>
    <g ansvg:layer="0" ansvg:type="TextStamp" ansvg:id="e8ee2a75-6fb0-4112-818f-810b089b0dd7">
      <rect x="7180" y="8314" width="1957" height="861" stroke="#0000FF" fill="none" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="20" />
      <text x="7230" y="8584" style="font-family:'Microsoft Sans Serif',Geneva,sans-serif; font-size:220px; fill:#0000FF; white-space: nowrap">
        <tspan x="7230" dy="0" xml:space="preserve">tannert</tspan>
        <tspan x="7230" dy="242" xml:space="preserve">31.12.2019, 22:38</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="7230" y="9109" style="font-family:'Microsoft Sans Serif',Geneva,sans-serif; font-size:220px; fill:#0000FF; white-space: nowrap" xml:space="preserve">Gebucht</text>
    </g>
    <g ansvg:layer="0" ansvg:type="TextStamp" ansvg:id="f7d99f5f-d8cb-4cc9-84a2-af6e4e4563cb">
      <rect x="7304" y="9573" width="2648" height="1857" stroke="#008000" fill="none" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="20" />
      <text x="7354" y="9843" style="font-family:'Microsoft Sans Serif',Geneva,sans-serif; font-size:220px; fill:#008000; white-space: nowrap">
        <tspan x="7354" dy="0" xml:space="preserve">tannert</tspan>
        <tspan x="7354" dy="242" xml:space="preserve">31.12.2019, 22:39</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="7354" y="10368" style="font-family:'Microsoft Sans Serif',Geneva,sans-serif; font-size:220px; fill:#008000; white-space: nowrap">
        <tspan x="7354" dy="0" xml:space="preserve">Geprüft und freigegeben!</tspan>
        <tspan x="7354" dy="242" xml:space="preserve">Kto: 111111</tspan>
        <tspan x="7354" dy="242" xml:space="preserve">Filiale: 11</tspan>
        <tspan x="7354" dy="242" xml:space="preserve">Betrag: 11</tspan>
        <tspan x="7354" dy="242" xml:space="preserve">Info:1111</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
    <g ansvg:layer="0" ansvg:type="Text" ansvg:id="cc4cf37e-9bb6-4be4-9a21-eb089cbe0db8">
      <text x="31430" y="25210" style="font-family:'Arial',sans-serif; font-size:220px; fill:#FF0000; white-space: nowrap;font-weight:bold" xml:space="preserve">Anmerkung</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Using following approach:

```cs
SvgConverter.DrawOnDocument(svgData, pdfDocument, documentPage);
```

will result in: [this is wrong](http://gaebolg.com/pub/elform/SVGAnno_wrong.png)

It should look like this one: [this is correct](http://gaebolg.com/pub/elform/SVGAnno_working.png)

Any other ideas?

Comment: which iText version do you use? I mean 7.y.x where y and x are... ?

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk Currently I am using 7.1.5

Comment: Could you try it with iText 7.1.6? The resultant PDF differs a lot from the one you shared

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk positioning and scaling still are off, seem similar to what I had before. The only thing that gets rendered correctly now is the color (it was black only before)

Comment: Removing the viewbox seems to be helpful at least in scaling issue, so perhaps the problem is with viewbox processing

Comment: The problem is with processing preserveAspectRatio and its default (none) value. The appropriate ticket is on the iText backlog and I will notify you once it's been picked up

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk Thanks for the info. Is there a link to the ticket? Sorry for the late reply, I was on vacation.

Comment: @Thyrador, the ticket that Uladzimir referred to has been closed, which means you will have access to this new functionality by using our SNAPSHOT (you can see how here: https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/installation-guides/installing-itext-7-net). We should also make a public release (7.1.9) in the beginning of December with the fix included.

Comment: @AndréLemos sorry for the late reply. I'll have a look when I have some time to implement the recent version of iText. Thanks anyway for letting me know :)

Comment: @AndréLemos So I had some time to test the new implementation. Unfortunately it still is a mess.
Some metadata positioning and size is still off. See updated post.